# A Trigonometry + complex number Equation

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

the question is:

Show that:
$$
[(\cos\theta - \cos\phi) + i(\sin \theta - \sin\phi)]^n + [(\cos\theta - \cos\phi) - i(\sin\theta - \sin\theta)] \\= 2^{n+1} \sin n \frac{(\theta - \phi)}{2}   \cos x \frac{\theta + \phi - \pi}{2}$$

I gave it a try following the pattern of the previous questions: https://ibb.co/d77by5

Comment: I edited you question to typeset formulas properly. Please check that the output corresponds to what you had in  mind. Also, what did you try to solve this problem?

Comment: What is that x doing over there?

Comment: Thankyou so much for editing the fraction part, I was actually typing this on an iPad (pretty hard). I honestly have no idea how to solve this. My teacher gave us a question like that but I never got to understand it and now this one is given to me as an assignment. I was hoping if someone could solve it or atleast give me a small explanation or a clue of solving it

Comment: And looks like multiple errors in typing. Please confirm the equation Again

Comment: There are no errors, my teacher just has his own way of solving them, in the previous question, he perpetually wrote cosx as (pi/2 -x), that might solve your question of where that x came from. Anyway, ill try to solve it myself

Comment: I'll share the answer

Comment: Btw, the class is BSc (Honors) the course is Pre-Calculus. Intermediate guys won't be able to solve it I guess

Comment: Given up already :3

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html

Comment: OR set $\cos\theta-\cos\phi=R\cos A, \sin\theta-\sin\phi=R\sin A$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find that your result in the question is valid only for even values of $n$ (as well containing typographical errors; it should be $\sin^n$ and $\cos(n...)$). My solution is as follows:

First note that

$$\cos\theta-\cos\phi=-2\sin\left(\frac{\theta+\phi}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{\theta-\phi}{2}\right) \\
\sin\theta-\sin\phi=2\cos\left(\frac{\theta+\phi}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{\theta-\phi}{2}\right)$$
Then
$$[(\cos\theta - \cos\phi) + i(\sin \theta - \sin\phi)]^n + [(\cos\theta - \cos\phi) - i(\sin\theta - \sin\theta)] \\=2^n\sin^n \left(\frac{\theta-\phi}{2}\right) \cdot \left\{\left[-\sin\left(\frac{\theta+\phi}{2}\right) +i\cos\left(\frac{\theta+\phi}{2}\right)\right]^n + \left[-\sin\left(\frac{\theta+\phi}{2}\right) -i\cos\left(\frac{\theta+\phi}{2}\right)\right]^n\right\}$$

Now, let $a=(\theta+\phi)/2$ and convert the terms in the curly braces to exponential form,

$$\{\ \frac{}{}\}=\left\{\left[-\left(\frac{e^{ia}-e^{-ia}}{2i}\right) +i\left(\frac{e^{ia}+e^{-ia}}{2}\right)\right]^n + \left[-\left(\frac{e^{ia}-e^{-ia}}{2i}\right) -i\left(\frac{e^{ia}+e^{-ia}}{2}\right)\right]^n\right\}\\=\frac{i^n}{2^n} \left\{ \left[e^{ia}-e^{-ia}+e^{ia}+e^{-ia} \right]^n + \left[e^{ia}-e^{-ia}-e^{ia}-e^{-ia} \right]^n\right\} \\=\frac{i^n}{2^n}  \left\{ 2^n e^{ina}+(-2)^ne^{-ina} \right\}=i^n\left\{ e^{ina}+(-1)^ne^{-ina} \right\}$$

Now,

$$i^n \left\{ e^{ina}+(-1)^ne^{-ina} \right\} = 2i^{n+1} \sin\left(n\frac{\theta+\phi}{2}\right) \ \  \text{for odd} \ n \\ i^n \left\{ e^{ina}+(-1)^ne^{-ina} \right\} = 2i^{n} \cos\left(n\frac{\theta+\phi}{2}\right) \ \  \text{for even} \ n $$

And finally,

$$[(\cos\theta - \cos\phi) + i(\sin \theta - \sin\phi)]^n + [(\cos\theta - \cos\phi) - i(\sin\theta - \sin\theta)] \\=(2i)^{n+1} \sin^n\left(\frac{\theta-\phi}{2}\right) \cdot \sin\left(n\frac{\theta+\phi}{2}\right) \ \  \text{for odd} \ n \\$$
and
$$[(\cos\theta - \cos\phi) + i(\sin \theta - \sin\phi)]^n + [(\cos\theta - \cos\phi) - i(\sin\theta - \sin\theta)] \\=2^{n+1} i^n \sin^n\left(\frac{\theta-\phi}{2}\right) \cdot \cos\left(n\frac{\theta+\phi}{2}\right) \ \  \text{for even} \ n \\$$

These can be combined into a single equation as follows:

$$[(\cos\theta - \cos\phi) + i(\sin \theta - \sin\phi)]^n + [(\cos\theta - \cos\phi) - i(\sin\theta - \sin\theta)] \\=2^{n+1} (-1)^n \sin^n\left(\frac{\theta-\phi}{2}\right) \cdot \cos\left(n\frac{\theta+\phi-\pi}{2}\right)$$

which is very close the answer in the original question, differing only by the factor $(-1)^n$. It's no wonder that it worked for even $n$. All the results have been verified by direct numerical simulation.

Comment: Thank you so much! That is exactly what I was looking for. Unfortunately, I got zero marks in the assignment but atleast thanks to you I know how to solve it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, let $$\cos\theta-\cos\phi=R\cos A,\sin\theta-\sin\phi=R\sin A$$

so that $$S=[(\cos\theta - \cos\phi) + i(\sin \theta - \sin\phi)]^n + [(\cos\theta - \cos\phi) - i(\sin\theta - \sin\phi)]^n=\{R(\cos A+i\sin A)\}^n+\{R(\cos A-i\sin A)\}^n$$

$$=R^n\left[(\cos A+i\sin A)^n+\dfrac1{(\cos A+i\sin A)^n}\right]$$

Using [de Moivre's Identity](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/deMoivresIdentity.html), $$S=2R^n\cos nA$$

Now $R^2=(R\sin A)^2+(R\cos A)^2=2-2\cos(\theta-\phi)=\left(2\sin\dfrac{\theta-\phi}2\right)^2$

WLOG $R=2\sin\dfrac{\theta-\phi}2$

again, $\dfrac{R\sin A}{R\cos A}=\dfrac{\sin\theta-\sin\phi}{\cos\theta-\cos\phi}$

Using [Prosthaphaeresis](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html) Formulas, $\tan A=-\cot\dfrac{\theta+\phi}2=\tan\dfrac{\theta+\phi-\pi}2$

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

Using [Prosthaphaeresis Formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html),

$$S=(\cos\theta - \cos\phi)+i(\sin \theta - \sin\phi)=2\sin\dfrac{\theta-\phi}2\left[-\sin\dfrac{\theta+\phi}2+i\cos\dfrac{\theta+\phi}2\right]$$

Now $-\sin\dfrac{\theta+\phi}2+i\cos\dfrac{\theta+\phi}2=\cos\dfrac{\theta+\phi+\pi}2+i\sin \dfrac{\theta+\phi+\pi}2$  as $\cos\left(A+\dfrac\pi2\right)=-\sin A,\sin\left(A+\dfrac\pi2\right)=\cos A$

Using [De Moivre's formula](https://brilliant.org/wiki/de-moivres-theorem/?quiz=de-moivres-theorem-raising-to-a-power-easy#),
$$S^n=2^n\sin^n\dfrac{\theta-\phi}2\left[\cos\dfrac{n(\theta+\phi+\pi)}2+i\sin\dfrac{n(\theta+\phi+\pi)}2\right]$$

Similarly,

$$\left[(\cos\theta - \cos\phi)-i(\sin \theta - \sin\phi)\right]^n=2^n\sin^n\dfrac{\theta-\phi}2\left[\cos\dfrac{n(\theta+\phi+\pi)}2-i\sin\dfrac{n(\theta+\phi+\pi)}2\right]$$